# Developing Spark Java Applications on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, apache-spark

I am trying to develop Spark Application on Eclipse. In the past, I have been successful with setting up Spark Scala projects on Eclipse. Now, I would like to setup a Spark Java Application on Eclipse. I am assuming I will need to use maven somehow, but I don't know exactly how I'm supposed to use it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up following the instructions to create a Java Maven project for Spark from [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html). After that, I converted the Maven project into an Eclipse project by executing `mvn eclipse:eclipse` from the root directory of the project that contains `pom.xml`.

Comment: In addition, one last step I needed to take was to add spark-assembly-*.jar into my build path. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can create your project in Eclipse as a Maven project, edit the pom and add the spark dependencies that you need ([core, mllib, etc.](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C1686516968)), then start with the java spark [examples](http://spark.apache.org/examples.html) provided and extend refactor from there depending on the problem that you try to solve. If you have more specific questions I would be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

add following dependencies in pom if you you are using spark streaming,kafka and others

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>$1.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```